# Case sensitive/insensitive comparisons for Data.Text?

Tags: haskell, text, comparison

I often need to do comparisons of Data.Text values with differing requirements for case sensitivity - this comes up frequently when I'm using [chatter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/chatter-0.1.0.5) for NLP tasks.

For example, when searching tokens for Information Extraction tasks, I frequently need to search based on equality relationships that are less restrictive than standard string equality.  Case sensitivity is the most common of those changes, but it's often a function of the specific token. A term like "activate" might usually be lower case, but if it's the first word in a sentence, it'll start with a leading capital, or if used in a title text may be in all caps or capitalized mid-sentence, so comparisons that ignore case make sense.  Conversely, an acronym (e.g., "US") has different semantics depending on the capitalization.

That's all to say that I can't easily create a typeclass wrapper for each equality class, since it's a value-driven aspect. (so the [case-insensitive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/case-insensitive) package doesn't look like it would work).

So far, I'm using `toLower` to make a canonical representation, and comparing those representations so I can create custom versions of Text comparison functions that take a sensitivity flag, e.g.:

```
matches :: CaseSensitive -> Text -> Text -> Bool
matches Sensitive   x y = x == y
matches Insensitive x y = (T.toLower x) == (T.toLower y)
```

However, I'm concerned that this takes extra passes over the input text.  I could imagine it fusing in some cases, but probably not all (eg: T.isSuffixOf, T.isInfixOf).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should really be using `toCaseFold` instead of `toLower` for case-insensitive comparisons. Maybe that doesn't matter so much when you know for sure all the text will be English, but it's still a good habit to use the more general approach.

Comment: Possibly you could use a top-level function `isCaseSensitive`, perhaps using a `Data.Set` of case-sensitive words (including "US" but not "Us" or "us"), and write an equality check which says `matches x y | isCaseSensitive x || isCaseSensitive y = x == y` and `| otherwise = toCaseFold x == toCaseFold y`

Answer (score 2):

If the style of the comparison is driven by the semantics of the thing being compared, does it make sense to pass those semantics be passed around with the actual text? You can also then normalise where appropriate to avoid the repeated passes later:

```
data Token = Token CaseSensitive Text -- Text is all lower-case if Insensitive
    deriving Eq
```

and perhaps define a smart constructor:

```
token Sensitive t = Token Sensitive t
token Insensitive t = Token Insensitive (T.toLower t)
```

This implies that the acronym "US" won't ever compare equal to the word "us", but that seems logical anyway.

You might also tag the values with something more detailed like acronym/word/... rather than just `Sensitive`/`Insensitive`.